# Nautilus not showing song's cover art of .m4a files

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, thumbnails

I have some songs in .m4a format. These songs have a cover art, but on Nautilus I can't see it. If I open it with VLC or If I put these songs on my Android phone, I can see the cover art, so I think it's an Ubuntu bug. If I give this command

```
file "the song.m4a"
```

I get this output:

> the song.m4a: ISO Media, MP4 Base Media v1 [IS0 14496-12:2003]

I tried to rename the song from ".m4a" to ".mp3", but nothing changed, it still doesn't show the thumbnail. But if I convert the song to mp3 using FFmpeg with this command

```
ffmpeg -i "the song.m4a" -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3
```

then it will works, I mean, on the "oputput.mp3", Nautilus will show the cover art. If it can help, I added the cover art to the song using "EasyTAG"

Comment: I don't think Nautilus (or Thunar) supports this.

Comment: @FedKad ok, but why does it works for .mp3? Maybe .m4a is bad format and I should convert them to .mp3?

Comment: In my system (Ubuntu 22.10) even covert arts in mp3 files are not displayed by Nautilus. I have no idea why.